# Is it possible to use SharedPreferences to change the default loadUrl of WebView when the app is launched the second time?

Tags: java, android, webview, sharedpreferences

I'm writing an app that uses WebView, and every time the app is launched, it goes to the same loadUrl. Here is me establishing the WebView. Followed by everything else that I want the WebView to do.

```
myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl(theUrlHere);
```

Now lets say that a certain condition was met by the user, may it be some action that was taken, or by just launching the app a second time, would it be possible to use `SharedPreferences` to change what url will load the next time the app is launched?

Edit: Can I get an example of how this can be achieved? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: yes, do you want its implementation?

Comment: Yes I should probably have clarified the question. Can I get an example of how to achieve it please?

Comment: done , check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared Preferences implementation:

```
private SharedPreferences pref;
```

then load it

```
pref = this.getSharedPreferences("myAppPref",MODE_PRIVATE);
```

now to put the new url if he met conditions you said about save the newUrl

```
pref.edit().putString("url","my new url to be loaded").commit();
```

and when the user reopen now(or opens for the first time) you have to load it from prefs:

```
String WebUrl= pref.getString("url","default url here");
myWebView.loadUrl(WebUrl); //this is ur webview
```

now if the value is NULL(not found) it will return default url(this case is for the first time he opens)

**NOTE THAT:** you should clear the cache on exit.

**NOTE THAT:** this value will be lost if the user clears the application data.

Comment: Hmm well I've no errors come up when I launch and relaunch it, but it still goes back to the default url. I think I may be placing the lines where they are supposed to be? I've placed the pref.edit() in the location where the change is supposed to happen, but on next launch, the default page still loads. I think I may have placed the last line in the wrong spot, or something is getting in the way of it. This is how the last two lines look before the webview loads         `myWebView.loadUrl(pref.getString("url", webPages.defaultUrl));`
        `myWebView.loadUrl(webPages.defaultUrl);`

Comment: Edited the original comment. Removing `myWebView.loadUrl(webPages.defaultUrl);` still loads the default page even if I've changed the default url where it needs to change.

Comment: oh i got it , just do this // String website = pref.getString("url", webPages.defaultUrl); myWebView.loadUrl(website );// I will include  that in solution so u can view it better

Comment: I can confirm that I was able to make it work. I've placed a few lines at the end that clear the cache on exit, and for some reason it returned the url to the default on. Removing the clearing of cache now changes the default url.

Comment: oh brilliant :) I will include that to the solution in case if someone faces the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

First, create this class to handle SharedPreferencess

```
  public class SharedPreferensessClass {

        static SharedPreferensessClass Instance;
        static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        Context context;

        public SharedPreferensessClass(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }



        public static SharedPreferensessClass getInstance(Context context) {

            if (Instance == null) {
                Instance = new SharedPreferensessClass(context);
            }
            init(context);
            return Instance;
        }


        public static void init(Context context) {
            if (sharedPreferences == null) {
                sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("app_name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            }

            if (editor == null) {
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            }
        }



    public static void setFirstTimeFalse() {

            editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
            editor.commit();
        }

        public static boolean getFirstTime() {
            return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("firstTime", true);
        }
   public static String getLink() {

        return sharedPreferences.getString("mainUrl", "");
    }

    public void setLink(String name) {
        editor.putString("mainUrl", name);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

then use this code to save the link first time

```
 if (SharedPreferensessClass.getInstance(getBaseContext()).getFirstTime()) {
            System.out.println("FIRSTTIMENOW");
            SharedPreferensessClass.getInstance(getBaseContext()).setLink("http://your_link");


            SharedPreferensessClass.getInstance(getBaseContext()).setFirstTimeFalse();
        }
```

The last step, use this code to get the link from SharePreferencess and put it in webView

```
myWebView.loadUrl(SharedPreferensessClass.getInstance(context).getLink());
```

note: the value will not be lost even if the user clears the data, because it will be the first time again :D

Happy coding!